# Lookup on an argument of a concatenation is just lookup on the whole concatenation using a raised or injected index

Tags: list, agda

I needed to use lists for something I'm doing and needed look-up,

```
open import Data.List.Properties
open import Data.List
open import Data.Fin

infix 10 _‼_
_‼_ : ∀ {X : Set} → (xs : List X) → Fin (length xs) → X
[] ‼ ()
(x ∷ xs) ‼ fzero = x
(x ∷ xs) ‼ fsuc i = xs ‼ i
```

I had to define it myself since I could not find it in the libraries.
I wish the libraries where easier to navigate and search.
**Any suggestions on better navigating or searching the libraries is much appreciated.**

I wanted to show that **look-ups on one argument of a concatenation is just lookup on the whole concatenation using a raised or injected index**, namely

```
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

‼-upper : ∀ {X} (pre main : List X) (i : Fin (length main))
      → let #pre+i = subst Fin (sym (length-++ pre)) (raise (length pre) i)in
      (pre ++ main) ‼ #pre+i ≡ main ‼ i
‼-upper = ?
```

and dually

```
open import Data.Nat
open import Relation.Binary using
open DecTotalOrder decTotalOrder renaming (refl to ≤ℕ-refl ; trans to ≤ℕ-trans ; reflexive to ≤ℕ-reflexive)

open import Data.Nat.Properties

‼-lower : ∀ {X} (main pos : List X) (i : Fin (length main))
      → let i∶Fin#m++p = inject≤ i (≤ℕ-trans (m≤m+n _ (length pos) (≤ℕ-reflexive (sym (length-++ main)))) in
      (main ++ pos) ‼ i∶Fin#m++p ≡ main ‼ i  
‼-lower = {!!}
```

I originally proved these two for a variant of vectors, `Fin n → X`, and used pasting of such sequences in place of concatenation. Now I just want to do the same thing but for the usual `List` datatype. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, when you have `subst` at the type level (which is a rather bad situation) you can eliminate it with `rewrite` at the value level. So let's try it:

```
‼-upper : ∀ {X} (pre main : List X) (i : Fin (length main))
      → let #pre+i = subst Fin (sym (length-++ pre)) (raise (length pre) i)in
      (pre ++ main) ‼ #pre+i ≡ main ‼ i
‼-upper  []       main i = refl
‼-upper (x ∷ pre) main i rewrite length-++ pre {main} = ?
```

Agda refuses:

```
w != foldr (λ _ → suc) 0 (pre ++ main) of type ℕ
when checking that the type
```

OK, something clashes with something. To remove this clashing we can instead rewrite by a "bigger" equation:

```
lem : ∀ {n m} (i : Fin n) (p : m ≡ n)
    -> subst Fin (sym (cong suc p)) (fsuc i) ≡ fsuc (subst Fin (sym p) i)
lem i refl = refl

‼-upper : ∀ {X} (pre main : List X) (i : Fin (length main))
      → let #pre+i = subst Fin (sym (length-++ pre)) (raise (length pre) i)in
      (pre ++ main) ‼ #pre+i ≡ main ‼ i
‼-upper  []       main i = refl
‼-upper (x ∷ pre) main i rewrite lem (raise (length pre) i) (length-++ pre {main})
                               = ‼-upper pre main i
```

I guess `‼-lower` is similar (also, it should be simpler if you replace `inject≤` with `inject+`, see `lookup-++-inject+` in `Data.Vec.Properties`). An alternative way is to define specialized versions of `raise` and `inject`:

```
raise-length : ∀ {α} {A : Set α}
             -> (xs ys : List A) -> Fin (length ys) -> Fin (length (xs ++ ys))
raise-length  []      ys i = i
raise-length (x ∷ xs) ys i = fsuc (raise-length xs ys i)

inject-length : ∀ {α} {A : Set α} {ys}
             -> (xs : List A) -> Fin (length xs) -> Fin (length (xs ++ ys))
inject-length  []       ()
inject-length (x ∷ xs)  fzero   = fzero
inject-length (x ∷ xs) (fsuc i) = fsuc (inject-length xs i)

‼-upper : ∀ {X} (pre main : List X) (i : Fin (length main))
        -> (pre ++ main) ‼ raise-length pre main i ≡ main ‼ i
‼-upper  []       main i = refl
‼-upper (x ∷ pre) main i = ‼-upper pre main i

‼-lower : ∀ {X} (main pos : List X) (i : Fin (length main))
        -> (main ++ pos) ‼ inject-length main i ≡ main ‼ i  
‼-lower  []        pos  ()
‼-lower (x ∷ main) pos  fzero   = refl
‼-lower (x ∷ main) pos (fsuc i) = ‼-lower main pos i
```

But I would simply use some form of vectors — why complicate your life?

Comment: I guess one avoids `subst` at the type level by using alternate data types.
Why does the rewrite using the "bigger" equation not crash?
Yeah I originally did these with vectors and it was easier, but I disliked having
lists and vectors intermixed and so decided to switch to one form.
Perhaps it would have been better to remain with both and continue to use conversions...
Anyhow, thanks a lot for the great reply :-)

Comment: @Musa Al-hassy, when the `List`s + `Vec`s setting becomes complicated I usually switch to just `Vec`s. Though, it may be inappropriate in your case. When you use `rewrite` Agda tries to define an auxuliary function and sometimes ([As mentioned above, generalisation does not always produce well-typed results. This happens when you abstract over a term that appears in the type of a subterm of the goal or argument types](http://agda.readthedocs.org/en/latest/language/with-abstraction.html#ill-typed-with-abstractions)) she just fails. "Enlarging" of an abstracted term allows to break dependencies.